# How to make a customized profile information UNIQUE in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm using a web project with asp.net Identity 2.0 on Visual Studio 2013. I've followed the instructions on this [page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx) to create a customized new field that I've called screenName. Everything seems to work well.

However I want to go one step further and have screenName unique in the database. Which means that the ApplicationUserManager must check if the screen name is taken before registering a user. How can I require a unique screenName and accomplish that?

Here are my codes:

AccountControler.cs (added screenName = model.screenName)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, screenName = model.screenName };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "bla bla bla", "Thank you for your bla bla bla registration. Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
                ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
                return View("DisplayEmail");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

AccountViewModel.cs

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
 [Required]
 [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "screenName")]
    public string screenName { get; set; }
}
```

IdentityModel.cs (added public string screenName { get; set; })

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string screenName { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Register.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.screenName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" }) 
<div class="col-md-10"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.screenName, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
</div>
</div>
```

SQL SERVER

```
 GO
 CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [screenNameIndex]
 ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([screenName] ASC);
```

The ApplicationUserManager is, for example, requiring a unique Email with the following code on the identityConfig.cs. How can I do the same for the custom screenName?

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
// Configure validation logic for usernames
manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to manually check if there is a record with this screen name exists in the DB:

Something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // somehow obtain your DbContext object
        var existsDuplicate = dbContext.Users.Any(u => u.screenName == model.screenName);
        if(existsDuplicate)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("screenName", "Screen Name is already taken, please choose another one");
            return View(model);
        }


        // the rest of controller is unchanged
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, screenName = model.screenName };

        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "bla bla bla", "Thank you for your bla bla bla registration. Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
            ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
            return View("DisplayEmail");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'm trying to implement your code but for some reason the dbContext can't be found although I have the EntityFramework 6.1.1 installed. I'm using MVC5. Am I missing a namespace?

Comment: OK I solved the problem by adding System.Data.Entity. But now I get another error message; 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' does not contain a definition for 'Users'......

Comment: You need to use your own database context, the one that inherits from `IdentityDbContext`. Code above is sample, don't take it literally.

Comment: Unfortunately it's going very bad. I couldn't figure out how to solve it. I'm not familiar with MVC and DbContext at all. Just going around like a rat in a vicious circle.